# Does "git mode" exist for bash?

Tags: bash, git, conemu

Honestly, I'm not really sure how to put it, but here goes. Does anything like "modes" (git mode, for instance) exist for bash? What I mean is:

I'm using git through bash **on Windows**. I have ConEmu running just for this, with one tab for each repository I'm working in. This works quite well. However, I find it rather tedious always having to type `git` before each command. What I'm looking for, is something that allows me to, rather than typing

```
git status
git checkout mybranch
git pull
```

just typing

```
status
checkout mybranch
pull
```

I imagine this would work by entering a "git mode", before I start using git. Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I imagine this would work by entering a "git mode", before I start using git.

`gitsh` appears to meet your needs<sup>1</sup>:

> The gitsh program is an interactive shell for git. From within gitsh
>   you can issue any git command, even using your local aliases and
>   configuration.
>
> Git commands tend to come in groups. Avoid typing git over and over and over by running them in a dedicated git shell:
>
> ```
> sh$ gitsh
> gitsh% status
> gitsh% add .
> gitsh% commit -m "Ship it!"
> gitsh% push
> gitsh% ctrl-d
> sh$
> ```

Source [gitsh/README.md at master · thoughtbot/gitsh](https://github.com/thoughtbot/gitsh/blob/master/README.md)

<sup>1 Caveat - I haven't used it</sup>

Comment: This look really great! Only, I forgot to add that I'm running Windows, which apparantly isn't supported by gitsh.

Comment: @torbonde If you install perl on Windows you can use https://github.com/caglar/gitsh